# How do i replace first letter in each word in a string?

Tags: c#, string

```
string str = "ghy saste mater"
```

How do I replace first letter in each word from `str` to the letter "w"?

So the new string would be:

> "why waste water"

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you expound your definition of _word_? For pattern-matching, that tends to have a very particular meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You would explode `string.Split()` your string using the delimeter of `" "` this would give you an array of strings and then you can loop over the entire array and call:

```
string.Replace(string[0], 'w')
```

A far more impressive manner of doing this would be using `Regex.Replace()` and writing a Regex to find the combination of a space and a character and then replace that string with a space and a w.

```
something like " a" would be replaced with " w"
```

This is really straitforward so I only provided some hints. Look-up what I talked about here and you'll be fine.

Comment: Here is a useful tool for trial and error when working with Regex..if you decide to go that way. http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string into an array and then change the first character in each element of the new array.

Something like:

```
string[] str_array = str.Split(' ');

for (int i = 0; i < str_array.Length; i++) {
    str_array[i] = "w" + str_array[i].Substring(1, str_array[i].Length);
}
```

Then you would have to turn the array back into a string.

Answer (score 0):

A neat way is to use [Regex.Replace()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace):

```
string str = "ghy saste mater";         
var strModified = Regex.Replace(str, @"\b\w", "w");
```

You also could use LINQ:

```
var str = "ghy saste mater"
var strModified = string.Join(" ", str.Split().Select(s => "w" + s.Substring(1, s.Length - 1))));
```

If you modify strings a lot, consider using [StringBuilder](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder) class:

```
var str = "ghy saste mater"
var strModified = str.Split().Select(s => "w" + s.Substring(1, s.Length - 1)).
    Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (b, s) => b.Append(s + " ")).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string str = "ghy saste mater";
        string[] parts = str.Split(' ');
        string result = string.Join(" ", parts.Select(p => "w" + (p.Length > 1 ? p.Substring(1, p.Length - 1) : "")).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through it.

```
string o = "";
o += str[0]
for (int i = 1; i < str.length; i++){
   o+=str[i-1] == ' ' ? 'w' : str[i];
}
```